# getCurrentSession call fails right after openSession

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi I have configured sessionFactory and MysqL datasource with transaction manager using hibernate. When I try to call getCurrentSession() on that factory right after openSession(), it throws HibernateException. How do I make it work?

Stacktrace of error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
at com.xyz.CommonTest.initTx(CommonTest.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
```

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="relationalDataSource"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>....</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
    logger.info("initTx called");
    // Either get a current session or open new one.
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        logger.info("did not find a current session, will try to open a new one",
                    exception);
    }
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (HibernateException exception) {
        logger.info("did not find a current session, will try to open a new one",
                    exception);
    }
```

edit:

You can do this by using.

hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

If you are looking for an automatic way to do this, then Ryan's answer below id correct.

Answer (score 3):

Merely opening a session doesn't associate it to the thread. You shouldn't be opening sessions manually anyway. Sessions should be opened and closed for you by Spring either 1) [when a transaction starts and ends](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html), or 2) as part of some kind of open-session-in-view implementation, which Spring provides [convenient implementations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) of. With either of those choices, you're assured that sessions are properly managed and cleaned up and that one will be available associated to the thread so you can use `getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I need to use <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> configuration for doing this automatically. on openSession call. I need to call it manually for unit tests. I am not implementing unit tests using spring's annotations. it's a plain junit implementation

Comment: That's probably not what you want, unless you're setting that for tests only. It's been a while since I looked at that part of the code, but I'm pretty sure that will wreak havoc with Spring's management of your Sessions. If you really don't want to use Spring's test framework, which is amazing for testing DAOs, you should be able to get away with manually binding the Session using the [TransactionSynchronizationManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html) to bind and unbind the Sessions.

Comment: I have set it to a property which is thread for tests and none for the rest. Won't it work?